# Prove that $B$, $C$, $M$, $N$ and $P$ are points of a cyclic polygon.

Tags: geometry

> $E$, $F$ and $D$ are points respectively on line $CA$, $AB$ and $BC$ such that $CE = EA$, $AF = FB$ and $ED = DF$. Given point $P$ sastified $\widehat{CET} = 90^\circ - \dfrac{\widehat{EDF}}{2} = \widehat{TFB}$. The tangent of the circumcircle of $\triangle{TEF}$ at point $T$ intersects line $CA$ and $AB$ respectively at points $M$ and $N$. The circumcircle of $\triangle{AFE}$ intersects line $AT$ at point $T$ $(P \not\equiv A)$. Prove that $B$, $C$, $M$, $N$ and $P$ are points of a cyclic polygon.

[image]

This might come as the most difficult geometry problem I've ever encountered. There's a clue and it is to let $Q = AP \cap (T, E, F)$ and prove that $AT$ and $AD$ are reflected one another in the bisector of $\widehat{CAB}$. $(AQ < AP)$

Working around the clue, I still can't figure it out. I suppose more points need to be set up.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the height of triangle FDE from vertex D. Since ED=DF this height is the bisector of $\angle FDE$. Hence we have:

$\angle DEF=\angle DFE=90-\frac{\angle EDF}{2}=\angle CET=\angle TFB$

FB is parallel to BC therefore:

$\angle EDC=\angle DEF=\angle CET$

Also:

$\angle AEF+\angle DEF+\angle DEC=180^o$

$\angle ACB=\angle AEF$

$\angle DEF=\angle EDC$

$\angle AEF+\angle FED+\angle DEC=180^o$

Due to data in question:

$\angle TEC=\angle BFT=\angle FED=\angle EDC$

⇒$\angle TEC=\angle DEC$

That is T locates on ED and triangle EDC is isosceles,Also triangle FNT is isosceles because NT and NF are tangent to circumcircle  of $\triangle TEF$ so we have:

$\angle ECD=\angle EDF=\angle FNT$

Therefore we have :

$\angle BCM=\angle BNM$

This  is possible only if points B, C, M and M are on a circle, because the sides of angles BNM and BCM cross each other.Similar reasoning can be used for point P.

Comment: How can you be sure that $T \in ED$?

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt, The reason is:$\angle AEF+\angle DEF+\angle DEC=180^o$

$\angle ACB=\angle AEF$ 

$\angle DEF=\angle EDC$

$\angle AEF+\angle AEF+\angle AEF=180^o$

Due to data in question:

$\angle TEC=\angle BET=\angle FED=\angle EDC$

⇒$\angle TEC=\angle DEC$

That is T locates on ED . I edited my answer.

Comment: I never said $3,AEF=180^o$, $AEF=ACB ≠EFD$ and the sum of internal angles of triangle DEC is $180^o$ which is equal to sum of angles <AEF=<ACB, <EDC and <DEC.

Comment: It was a typo ,I corrected it.

Comment: If $\widehat{TEC} = \widehat{BFT} = \widehat{FED} = \widehat{EDC}$ then $\widehat{TEC}$ should be equal to $\widehat{EDC}$, not $\widehat{DEC}$.

Comment: DEC=BFT and there are both oppsite the arc DE. So CE must be tangent to circumcircle of FED at E. Now DEC=TEC ,due to statement, so T must be on DE, in this case surly TEC=EDC.

Comment: If $T$ locates on $ED$, it can similarly be proven that $T$ locates on $DF \implies T \equiv ED \cap DF$ or $T \equiv D$, which requires $\triangle ABC$ to be isoceles.

Comment: Not necerily, if you extend ET it crosses the circle at a point like T', if TEC=DFE then T' must be coincident with D. Let' chat about it.

Comment: Well, the figure I've drawn is geometrically correct and $T \not\in ED$ nor $T \not\in DF$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96448/discussion-between-sirous-and-le-thanh-dt).